# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'

Tags: 20.04, python, dependencies, python3, pip

I manually installed python3.8.5 on my Ubuntu laptop after I accidentally deleted it from /usr/bin. I have successfully linked my python python3 and pip3 to my computer so when I type `which <either python, python3, or pip3>` it gives a path and when I type them alone I get the shell.

For example,

```
jayakumar@jayakumarUbuntu:~/Downloads$ pip3 install pygame
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (21.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 21.8 MB 17.1 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-2.1.2
```

*just to show it's working

my ubuntu applications and some other apps (vscode, android studio, etc.) are not launching and any ways to fix it without reinstalling my desktop would be nice thanks.

When I run them from the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
```

Comment: Yup, you've removed an integral part of you operating system. Ubuntu relies on its version of python and its tool collection. There are >100 questions in this forum about problems after installing another python version... You might try to reinstall the original Ubuntu python files.

Comment: Or save yourself a lot of time and grief and reinstall the OS. Basically you ripped out the heart of the system.

Comment: @David Is that the only possible way? I do not have a 256 gb usb to back up my data in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You might after struggling and trying various fixes over many weeks get it working. Or in a couple of hours have a working system. Never mess with the default python.